# Are there any shaiva sampradaya/ parampara acharyas?

Tags: shaivism, kashmiri-shaivism, shaiva-siddhanta

Are there any parampara/ sampraday in shaivism that give agamic diksha. Just like Chinna Jeeyar Swamy of Sri Ramanujacharya sect in Andhra Pradesh who give vaishnava agamic diksha. Are there any famous shaivite sects in India?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE. Kindly visit [How Does a New User Get Started on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). Have an enriching journey in here.

Comment: Also, why or why not Shaivism is popular or not popular, is an opinion eliciting question, which might lead to question's closure.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Part of your question looks like personal advice which we don't allow on this site. You may want to remove that.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry. I'm new to this so I was unsure how to frame the question. I have edited it now.